# Date value not showing value pulled from database

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, ejs

My setup is SailsJS + Mongo using EJS for inserting database values onto my page.

On my page I'm using a standard HTML form date picker and to set a date. Using this I can successfully submit the selected date to my database with no issues. The date format looks like this in my DB: `2015-06-09T00:00:00.000Z`

I can call this value into a regular text field, but if I try to populate a date picker value, it just shows up like the value has not been populated.

Is there something I'm missing or some inbetween step which needs to be taken?
Here is what my form entry looks like for the date picker:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="resStart">When do you need the space?</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<%= request.resStart %>" name="resStart">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="resEnd">When will you be done with the space?</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" value="<%= request.resEnd %>" name="resEnd">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What value do you see in the page: `<... value="2015-06-09T00:00:00.000Z" ...>`?

Answer (score 0):

your value in DB is actually a datetime value. i think just passing it to date picker will not be recognized. it needs to be changed to date format.  the input tag in your html is date type. i think change this to text will get the value appear. but to make the date picker work you will need to do some data conversion between the datetime format 2015-06-09T00:00:00.000Z and 2015-06-09